# Using switch to select tibble variables in RShiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, switch-statement, tibble

I'm currently building my first RShiny app and am using tidyverse and ggplot. I have a block of code for plotting a chart and am trying to use a switch statement to select variables to plot based on user input. For example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("catVar", 
                  label = "Categories:",
                  choices = c("choice 1",
                              "choice 2",
                              "choice 3",
                              "choice 4",
                              "choice 5"),
                  selected = "choice 1")),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("barChart")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$barChart <- renderPlot({
    xData <- switch(input$catVar,
                    "choice 1" = var1,
                    "choice 2" = var2,
                    "choice 3" = var3,
                    "choice 4" = var4)

    chart <- 
      tibble %>%
        group_by(xData) %>%
        ggplot(aes(xData)) +
          geom_bar(fill = "black") +
          ylab("Count") +
          xlab(input$catVar) +
          coord_flip()

    print(chart)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I run the app it reports "Error: object 'var1' not found". Is there another way to write the name of a tibble column in the switch statement so that the xData substitution in ggplot works?

Comment: If it is a string, you need quotes `"var1"` or else, if it is an object, didn't find the object defined

Answer (score 0):

`var1` through `var4` are not created anywhere in your code, so R doesn't know what you're talking about. The way that I've been able to get this to work in the past is to change your input to `selectInput('catVar', 'Categories:', choices=c('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'))` and then change your case statement to `xData <- rlang::syms(input$catVar)`. This of course requires you to have the `rlang` package installed. Once that's done, also change `groupBy(xData)` to `groupBy(!!!xData)`. Your code should now work as intended.